# Scala, Tapir, ZIO - add metrics interceptor with default error handler

Tags: scala, prometheus, zio, tapir

Have a question regarding Prometheus metrics in Tapir and ZIO. I have a simple code:

```
val metrics = PrometheusMetrics.default[Task]()
val options: ZioHttpServerOptions[Any] = ZioHttpServerOptions
    .customiseInterceptors
    .metricsInterceptor(metrics.metricsInterceptor())
    .options
```

and it works correct when I call `localhost:8080/metrics`, I see metrics.

But when I added default error handler:

```
val metrics = PrometheusMetrics.default[Task]()
def failureResponse(msg: String): ValuedEndpointOutput[_]=
   ValuedEndpointOutput(jsonBody[MyFailure], MyFailure(msg))
val options: ZioHttpServerOptions[Any] = ZioHttpServerOptions
    .customiseInterceptors
    .metricsInterceptor(metrics.metricsInterceptor())
    .defaultHandlers(failureResponse, notFoundWhenRejected = true)
    .options
```

It doesn't work. Instead of metrics I see now error (404) which was caught during request to  `localhost:8080/metrics`. Honestly, don't know why. Is it possible to fix it somehow and keep error handler along with metrics interceptor?

**EDIT:**
Metrics endpoint:

```
def metricsEndpoint = ZioHttpInterpreter(options).toHttp(metrics.metricsEndpoint)
```

Comment: Are you sure you are adding the metrics endpoint in both cases?

Comment: Hm maybe you are interpreting your endpoints and the metrics endpoint separately - that is, adding the `zhttp.http.Http` twice? If so, combined with `notFoundWhenRejected = true`, would return a 404 when the first `Http` is run.

Comment: Yes, I use this options in `ZioHttpInterpreter(options).toHttp(...)`. I edited post and added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is most probably due to separately interpreting the "main" endpoints and the metrics endpoint as ZIO Http's `Http` value.

Consider the following:

```scala
val mainHttp = ZioHttpInterpreter(options).toHttp(mainEndpoints)
val metricsHttp = ZioHttpInterpreter(options).toHttp(metricsEndpoints)

Server.start(8080, mainHttp <> metricsHttp)
```

If the `notFoundWhenRejected = true` option is used, when the request `/metrics` comes in, it is first handled by `mainHttp`. However, that value doesn't know how to handle this request - hence it is rejected. But as we specified the mentioned option, rejections are turned into 404s, hence the answer.

The default value for that option is `false`. In this situation, the `/metrics` request is rejected by the `mainHttp` value, but this isn't converted into a 404 response, instead processing continues with `metricsHttp`.

The proper solution, to have both `/metrics` working, and the `notFoundWhenRejected = true` option, is to interpret all endpoints at once. Then, the 404 will be returned only when none of the endpoint (neither the main, nor the metrics one) matches the request:

```scala
val http = ZioHttpInterpreter(options)
  .toHttp(mainEndpoints ++ metricsEndpoints)

Server.start(8080, http)
```

Comment: So `mainEndpoints` and `metricsEndpoints` here are `zServerLogic` for every interpreters?

Comment: yes, these are your server endpoints; you can combine them in a list and interpret in one go

Comment: Ok, it works no correctly. Metrics can be seen and not existing urls are correctly caught. It is what I needed. Thank you.